# Align space and punctuation with one regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I have a couple of strings like:

```
test
test. hi
test,  hello.(actual whitespace)
hello -this is a test
hello v2 , i am a " test" as well
```

I'd like to align punctuation following some set of rules like:

1. commas should have a trailing space but not a leading one
2. hyphens should have spaces on both sides if there is at least one space on any side of it in the original string
3. dots should have s trailing space aside from a case when they are on the end of the string
4. quotation marks (single and double) should not have spaces on opening/closing sides
5. etc etc (other rules will be added as needed, covering first 4 is enough for this case)

So the output will be like:

```
test
test. hi
test, hello.
hello - this is a test
hello v2, i am a "test" as well
```

My questions are: is it possible to do it in one go - with a single regex instead of creating a regex for each case, and if yes - what would be the regex that can do that? Is there a more efficient way of doing it than in a single regex (if it's possible), especially considering the fact that i'm already iterating through the whole string to remove some special unicode characters?

Comment: My take on your answers: yes, yes

Comment: Please avoid asking for the community to do the work for you, instead of asking valid programming questions.

Comment: We can't answer based on 'etc etc', be more specific.

Comment: this etc shows that there will be other rules, i will add them as i need, just a generic technique that will cover the first 4 will be more than enough

Comment: Rule 4 is not very simple for a regex. How do you tell open from close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `MatchEvaluator` `delegate` version of `Regex.Replace`, you can use a `Regex` to find problematic punctuation, and then use conditional logic to return the proper result. This doesn't handle rule 4 - it isn't easy to recognize open versus close quotes in a regular expression.

```
List<String> src;
var p = new Regex(@"\s*,\s*|\s+-\s*|-\s+|\s*\.\s+(?=.)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var ans = src.Select(s => p.Replace(s, m => {
            var mv = m.Value.Trim();
            return mv == "," ? ", " : mv == "-" ? " - " : mv == "." ? ". " : mv;
        })).ToList();
```

Comment: still an answer as helps from technical side, thank you